# Is there a way I can get the Return Type of the generator function?

Tags: typescript, iterator

I want to get the return type of the generator function.
For example

```
function* test(){
  yield 'a';
  yield 123;

  return true;
}

// what I'm trying to get
type A = GetGeneratorReturn<test>; // -> A has type boolean
```

What I'm currently at.

```
type B = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof test>['next']>['value'];
// B has type `true | "a" | 123`
```

(I thought I could get return type if I get the first item of Union type B)

Comment: Any ordering of the constituents of a union is an implementation detail of the compiler... `X | Y` is equivalent to `Y | X` so any solution which pulls `X` or `Y` out of `X | Y` is probably fraught with peril.    Why do you need this?  A use case might help someone provide alternative solutions.

Comment: There are ways to do this, and someone will probably post one, I want to second jcalz's warning. Just don't do it (or if you do, don't use it in any production code)

Comment: Oh I see, I want to get the return type of the generator function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983) which talks about this problem among others, but it's quite old and it doesn't look like anyone's tending to it since some of the other issues have been addressed.  I see [recent mentions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29288#issuecomment-455710660) of it here and there.  The most relevant issue out there seems to be [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29982).  If this matters to you, you might want to head over to GitHub and give these issues some s.

For now it seems that generator typings in TypeScript only give you access to an undifferentiated union of the `yield` types and the `return` type.   And unfortunately, you can't rely the ordering of a union type.  It's an implementation detail of the compiler; since `X | Y` is equivalent to `Y | X`, the compiler feels free to change one to the other.  And sometimes it does:

```
function* test() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 123;
  return true;
} // function test(): IterableIterator<true | "a" | 123>

function* oops() {
  yield true;
  yield 123;
  return 'a'
} // function oops(): IterableIterator<true | "a" | 123>
```

The return type of `oops()` is *exactly the same* as the return type of `test()`.  That means your idea of extracting the first/last element of a union is a non-starter.

It's possible there's a workaround that will help, especially if you can mess with the generator definition and don't mind some phantom types floating around:

```
type Returnable<T> = { __returnedType?: T } & T
const ret = <T>(t: T) => t as Returnable<T>;
type GeneratorReturn<T extends (...args: any) => IterableIterator<any>> =
  ReturnType<T> extends IterableIterator<infer I> ?
  NonNullable<Extract<I, Returnable<unknown>>['__returnedType']> : never

function* test() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 123;
  return ret(true); // only use ret() here
} 

function* oops() {
  yield true;
  yield 123;
  return ret('a'); // only use ret() here
} 

type TestRet = GeneratorReturn<typeof test>; // true
type OopsRet = GeneratorReturn<typeof oops>; // "a"
```

Which works as far as it goes, but might not be something you want to pursue.  Oh well, sorry that I can't find a better answer here.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You can now do like that:

```
type GeneratorReturnType<T extends Generator> = T extends Generator<any, infer R, any> ? R: never;
type TestType =  GeneratorReturnType<ReturnType<typeof test>>; // bool
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgKgAQwKYGcYAoCUqA3sKqgJ5wYA2AJqgOQCGDA3KRVXagIwBMAZnZkAThhhgREdCLAZ2AX2ChIsRClQIEABywFiHSjXoxZ8w13r8hHMRKmMWwBamUxy2jKgDiGCBhEmGAQRACVxSQgAFQ8MAB4o1AwAD0wIWiwfPwCgkIA%20VABeVESUtIys-0DgkTimCHIAGlQ4CBAA1FDm%20vICgH5OgC5UfwA3AOB3TxLsGBjp4sqcmvD7aNi41cj5%20KmMBBB0Wby8ydjUAHkdLB2ipeqQrakdzYjnjb2DzWuToA)